# angular ui router - get only query string params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Wondering if there's a built in way to get only query string params without additional route params?

Example with `$stateParams` from the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service):

```
// If you had a url on your state of:
url: '/users/:id/details/{type}/{repeat:[0-9]+}?from&to'

// Then you navigated your browser to:
'/users/123/details//0'

// Your $stateParams object would be
{ id:'123', type:'', repeat:'0' }

// Then you navigated your browser to:
'/users/123/details/default/0?from=there&to=here'

// Your $stateParams object would be
{ id:'123', type:'default', repeat:'0', from:'there', to:'here' }
```

I'm looking to distinguish from/to in this case from the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$location.search()` from the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service does exactly this.

Example from docs:

```
// given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```